# Android EditText Transparent Background

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I want to have a transparent background for Android EditText widget. How is that possible?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try this

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: i want to do this in layout file. it is possible?

Comment: how we set "@null" programitically in java codes ?

Answer (score 45):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: i want to do this in layout file. it is possible?

Answer (score 13):

You can also set it using java code

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 7):

1. in xml file you use this property:

   `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`
2. and in java file   run time in onCreate method use:

   `edittext.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 5):

Very simple:

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Comment: It's not good idea to play with alpha - this is a very (!!!) common source of very (!!!) poor rendering performance.

Comment: Also, 0.5 is not transparent. It's precisely semi-transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Put this property in edittext:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it programitically like this:

```
 TypedValue value= new TypedValue();
 getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, value, true);

  myButton.setBackgroundResource(value.resourceId);
```

Answer (score 1):

EditText, like any other view/component can be customized in the xml file.
You just need to include below attribute in the EditText attributes.

```
 android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

set this in layout will work

```
android:background="@color/transparent
```

and add this in colors.xml

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

For XML code use:

```
android:background="@color/transparent
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

For Java code:

```
myEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score -6):

Use translucent theme

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```