# Android EditText with transparent theme

Tags: android, android-edittext

I used the following theme on my activity:

```
<style name="Theme.TranslucentDarkGrey" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/translucent_dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

This gives me a translucent grey background to see the back activity, problem I'm facing is I have an EditText that doesn't fill up the parent. If I remove the Theme above it fills up nicely. here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Nevermind solved it using this:

```
<style name="Theme.TranslucentDarkGrey" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/translucent_dark_grey</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check this question, it may be of your help: [Android EditText Transparent Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712378/android-edittext-transparent-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind solved it using this:

```
<style name="Theme.TranslucentDarkGrey" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/translucent_dark_grey</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply below code line in your edit-box it will give you transparent background.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: This just makes the EditText totally transparent with floating words which mixes with the background and looks messy.

Comment: Can you define partially Transparent? as per your query you are looking for transparent back and I think I am right as per question.