# Custom EditText Shape Android

Tags: android, xml

im trying to make a custom red EditText that takes the background of the fragment layout. I tried a lot of things but i cannot make it transparent in order to use the layout color background. Any ideas?

[image: EditText shape]

I tried with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_background"/> -red
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/trans_background"
    android:top="0dp"/>
<item
    android:bottom="@dimen/input_line_width"
    android:drawable="@drawable/trans_background"
    android:left="@dimen/input_line_width"
    android:right="@dimen/input_line_width"
    android:top="0dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Why don't you simple generate a red 9-patch drawable using http://android-holo-colors.com/?

Comment: Check this for transparent background

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712378/android-edittext-transparent-background

Comment: @Xjasz Thanks for the answer, i already tried that and no luck

Comment: @Natix thanks for your answer, i solved using 9-patch generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to accomplish this issue i used [this page](http://android-holo-colors.com) to draw a 9-patch as @Natix recommended me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `@drawable/trans_background`s background color code is `#00000000`

Note: Here color code is not 6digit number. Its 8 digit where 1st 2 digits are for the opacity of the background. It should remove the background visibility.

Comment: Hi, i already tried that and when i put #00000000 it change all the rectangle in red. :(