# Transparent EditText Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to make my `EditText` in my android studio project transparent. I want it to look like the EditText here [image]

But mine doesn't look like that even though I have tried using `transparent` and `ffffff` can someone please help me with this ? I want my edit text background to look like the one in the image I showed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712378/android-edittext-transparent-background)

Comment: Because that isn't transparent.  Fully transparent wouldn't have the frosted look.  Its partially transparent, alphaing some white.  You'd want an alpha byte somewhere between FF and 00  (probably much closer to 00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg" />
```

edittext_bg.xml in drawables folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#80ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Change color value of `<solid android:color="#80ffffff" />` to adjust transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Add`background` attribute to set edittext background like this `android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"`

**try this code**

edit_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid
    android:color="#E288CB"/>
<corners
    android:radius="5dp"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C71D8B"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".TransparentEditActivtiy">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if you want to adjust the transparent change the alpha in color I gave as #FF000000 OR #FFFFFFFF, and you can change the first 2 caracters (alpha) to change degre of transparence